# Official LEGO charity programs

Tags: lego-group

Many consumer-oriented corporations have official charity programs where products or money are donated to deserving causes. I was wondering if The LEGO Group has any such programs --- and if so, where can one apply for donations?

For instance, I believe it would bring happiness to hospitalized children to receive a simple Lego set (such as a polybag) to play with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first hit on Google for "LEGO charity" is this: http://service.lego.com/en-us/helptopics/lego-company/charity-and-donations. From that page:

> What charitable activities is the LEGO Group involved in?
>
> We take our responsibility for making children's lives better very
>   seriously, so we run a number of charitable programs.
>
> Usually, [our local offices](http://aboutus.lego.com/en-us/lego-group/locations) use their knowledge of what local children
>   need to partner with initiatives and charities.
>
> On a global level, we help children through the activities of [the LEGO
>   Foundation](http://www.legofoundation.com/#xlink). If you'd like to know more about how we understand our
>   responsibility and what we do, there's lots more information in the
>   [About Us](http://aboutus.lego.com/en-us/sustainability) section of this website.

Sounds like that should cover your question. Check out the www.legofoundation.com website as well.

Comment: I could not find much concrete information about charitable activities using the links provided, but corporate buzz words and pictures of happy people were abundant. I guess I have to dig deeper or contact my local Lego office.

Comment: Assuming you are looking at getting LEGO to sponsor/assist with a local charitable program (and not a big global reach effort), I think you should talk to LEGO close to you, and find out what criteria they use for sponsoring events. This should give you guidelines as to whether your idea would qualify for sponsorship/donations. The LEGO Foundation seems to be more aligned with larger programs (I can see a tie-in with Unicef on their website).